# Como alterar através de eventos o type de um input?

Tags: html5, input, bootstrap-4

Estou tentando utilizar o `input` com `type="date"` da seguinte forma:

- Quando estiver na **GRID XS..MD** irá utilizar o `select` nativo do aparelho
- Quando estiver na **GRID LG..XL** irá utilizar o `input` padrão

Eu tentei fazer o seguinte:

```
<input type="text" id="step-one-form-date-of-birth" class="form-control " aria-describedby="Date of Birth" placeholder="Data de Nascimento" onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')">
```

Porém a troca não ocorre, como proceder com boas práticas?

Comment: O que seria esse `input` padrão? Seria o `type="text"`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss o padrão é `type="date"`, quando ele estiver em mobile ele vai usar o date, quando estiver em dispositivos como notebook/desktop vai utilizar o `type="text"`.

Comment: Isso deve responder se eu redimensionar a tela? Por exemplo, acessar no desktop e reduzir a tela até o tamanho de um mobile

Answer (score 2):

A resposta acima do **@hugocsl** satisfaz a solução, porém como eu respondi ao mesmo nos comentários, gasta-se muitas linhas de códigos e tempo de manutenção, pela frente poderia ter algum tipo de problema.. Por fim agradeço o seu tempo para retirar a minha dúvida.

Então pesquisando muito afundo encontrei uma excelente solução:

- Utilizar o [Jquery Mask](https://plugins.jquery.com/mask/), para mascarar os dados inseridos.
- Utilizar o `type="tel"`, para utilizar o **teclado nativo** dos **smartphones/tablets e ipads** (Referente somente a valores números).

Animação em um dispositivo dentro da grid **LG..XL**:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Animação em um dispositivo dentro da grid **xs (representando smartphone)**:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Achei o teclado numérico uma boa opção para inserir datas, interessante isso, vc poderia usa-lo tb para CPF

Comment: @hugocsl eu também, eu só não me conformo com a nomenclatura do type do input.. Poderia existir uma nomenclatura para estes casos, por exemplo: CEP, CPF e etc.

Comment: Só que CEP (ZIP Code no USA) e CPF (Social Security nos USA), fossem universais como a Data e o Tel que são apenas números....

Answer (score 1):

**Opção 1**

Vc tem duas opções uma é esconder um `input` e mostrar outro dependendo da largura da tela, esse opção é só com CSS e com as Classes do Bootstrap `d-block` e `d-none` usando o bracking point `-sm-`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da imagem acima:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="date" class="form-control d-block d-sm-none" id="" aria-describedby="" placeholder="">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control d-none d-sm-block" id="" aria-describedby="" placeholder="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Opção 2**

Com JS quando a tela forma maior que X vc troca o `type` do `input`. No caso usei o que seria o *breacking point* `-sm-` do Bootstrap `540px`. Quando a tela for maior que isso eu troco o atributo type do `input` pra `text`, se a tela for menor fica como `type=date`

Exiba em página toda para ver o `input` mudando de um tipo para outro. Nessa técnica vc mostra apenas um `input` e troca o tipo dele, coisa que não é possível fazer no Bootstrap ou mesmo com CSS

```js
function myFunction(x) {
    var inp = document.querySelector('#troca')
    if (x.matches) { // If media query matches
        document.getElementById('troca').type = 'date';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('troca').type = 'text';
    }
}

var x = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 540px)")
myFunction(x) 
x.addListener(myFunction)
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="troca" aria-describedby="" placeholder="">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Olá hugocsl meu amigo, obrigado pela resposta. Eu irei dar a pontuação para ti, pois de certa forma ela está correta, porém é uma solução que gasta muitas linhas de código e poderia ter problemas para manutenção.. Bem eu achei uma solução excelente na "dark web", irei postar a mesma aqui.. Porém te faço uma pergunta, é boa pratica utilizar o type="tel" para abrir o teclado nativo do mobile, mesmo os dados inseridos não sendo um telefone?

Comment: @THIAGODEBONIS o input Date só aceita numerais, e o teclado do Tel é um teclado numérico, então acredito que o usuário não vai se sentir frustado por esse motivo, talvz até facilite a vida dele com os números maiores e que ficam mais fácil de serem clicados. Posta ai pra gente ver o que pega com esse código `dark` rss

Comment: Segue meu amigo..